# BASH script not work properly in crontab

Tags: bash, cron, screen-capture

Below line of my bash script not write output of `/tmp/DPE_SC/LoadUnits/ttx/bin/deasn9 -b -a cdrr6 $fnames` to file `$dst_dir"/"$fstat"-"$fnames".txt` when I execute from crontab.
It only creates empty file named `$dst_dir"/"$fstat"-"$fnames".txt`
Sure it works properly from command line manually.

> /tmp/DPE_SC/LoadUnits/ttx/bin/deasn9 -b -a cdrr6 $fnames > $dst_dir/$fstat-$fnames.txt

What is my mistake?

This is my whole script

> #!/bin/bash
>
> export PATH=/tmp/DPE_SC/LoadUnits/ttx/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/tmp/DPE_SC/Tools:/usr/X11R6/bin
>
> src_dir=/charging/chsLog/ready
>
> dst_dir=/Core/cdr
>
> cd $src_dir
>
> lastfile=`cat $dst_dir/last_cdr.txt`
>
> filenames=`ls -t | grep ^chsLog`
>
> fcounter=1
>
> for fnames in $filenames
>
> ```
>      do
>
>              fstat=`stat -c %y ${fnames} | cut -d '.' -f1`
>
>              fstat=`echo ${fstat//[^0-9]/}`
>
>              if [[ $fstat -gt $lastfile ]]
>
>              then
>
>                      if [[ $fcounter -eq 1 ]]
>
>                      then
>
>                              echo $fstat > $dst_dir/last_cdr.txt
>
>                              let "fcounter = $fcounter + 1"
>
>                      fi
>
>                      deasn9 -b -a cdrr6 ${fnames} > $dst_dir/$fstat-${fnames}.txt
>
>              fi
>
>      done
> ```

Comment: It sounds like /tmp/DPE_SC/LoadUnits/ttx/bin/deasn9 isn't working in crontab context, but we're not going to be able to figure out why it doesn't work just from seeing the line used to run it...

Comment: @GordonDavisson As your request, Here I put my whole script. It works well from cmdline. But only `deasn9 -b -a cdrr6 ${fnames} > $dst_dir/$fstat-${fnames}.txt` line not work from crontab. I sees that line `echo $fstat > $dst_dir/last_cdr.txt` worked well from crontab.

Comment: from stderr msg shell tried to open file named cdrr6.spe. But cdrr6 should be part of deasn9 binary's option. How could I tell it to shell cdrr6 is deasn9's option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I mistaken. cdrr6 was not only option. It is cdr formatting library. Then I exported LIB path from scipt.
Now it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that your `.profile`, `.bashrc`, et. al. are not available from inside cron.

Environment variables have to be defined directly in the crontab.

e.g.

```
fstat=myValue
fname=aName
@hourly myJob ${fstat} ${fname}
```